# Moving a Reality Composer entity after loading from Xcode?

Tags: arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I have used Reality Composer to build an AR scene, which currently has one object (as I understand, this is an entity).  Using Xcode, I am loading this Reality Composer scene, which functions as expected.  However, I would like my user to have the ability to scale or move the object, while still retaining all of my animations and Reality Composer setup.

I am using this code to load my object;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
    let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()
    boxAnchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

    arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)

}
```

I have attempted to implement traditional `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` to no avail.  I do see such options such as `EntityScaleGestureRecognizer`, though I've yet to figure out how to implement this accordingly.  I do see, from some reading, that my "entity" needs to conform to `hasCollision`, but it seems that I might be missing something, as I'd imagine Reality Composer must offer some sort of interaction functionality, given its simplicity to build AR experiences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()    
boxAnchor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
let box = boxAnchor.group as? Entity & HasCollision
arView.installGestures(for: box!)

set Physics for the box in Reality Composer

see https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119773
```